# How to write the program that prints out all positive integers between 1 and given number , alternating between the two ends of the range?

Tags: python, while-loop, flip

The program should work as follow:

```
Please type in a number: 5
1
5
2
4
3
```

My code doesn't do the same. I think there is should be the 2nd loop, but I don't really understand how can I do it. Could you possibly give me a hint or advice to solve this task. Thanks.
My code looks like this:

```
num = int(input("Please type in a number:"))
n=0
while num>n:
    a = num%10
    num -= a
    num = num/10
    print(a)
    n = n + 1   
print(n)
```

Comment: i am trying to understand the question but i am not able to. Can you try to explain the output logic?

Comment: I enter a number, let's say 6, and I want the program show me all integers from 1 to 6 in certain order: 1
6
2
5
3
4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```py
num = int(input("Please type in a number:"))
number_list = [i+1 for i in range(num)]

while number_list:
    print(number_list.pop(0))
    number_list.reverse()
```

Comment: O(n^2) because of  `.reverse()`

Comment: Thanks! I'm beginner in python and stucked with this type of tasks.  How it possible to change this code that it shows the sequence in different order like 2 1 4 3 5 (vertically).

Answer (score 1):

```
x = flag = 1
for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
    print(x)
    flag, x = -flag, x+flag*i
```

Comment: Cute, but the degree of head-scratching required seems excessive for this problem. This feels like a perl solution....

Answer (score 1):

```
number = int(input())
 
left = 1
right = number
 
while left < right:
    print(left)
    print(right)
    left += 1
    right -= 1
# In case of odd numbers
if left == right:
    print(left)`
```

Comment: Could you explain some of your code, to make it easier to understand for future readers?

Answer (score 0):

Not the most space-efficient way, but if the number is relatively small, an easy approach is to build a list and just pop off either end in turn:

```
nums = list(range(1, int(input("Please type in a number:"))+1))
while nums:
    print(nums.pop(0))
    if nums:
        print(nums.pop())
```

Comment: so many list relocations, why not just use negative index?

Comment: Minimizing the amount of state to keep track of.  For a linear-time/constant-space solution I'd use `range` and `zip_longest` but that feels out of scope for a beginner question :P

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly the most memory efficient way would be to use `itertools.zip_longest` and `range`s:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

n = int(input("Please type in a number: "))
for lower, upper in zip_longest(range(1, n // 2 + 1), range(n, n // 2, -1)):
    if lower:
        print(lower)
    print(upper)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a cute way to do it:

```
l = list(range(1,6))
def index_generator():
    while True:
        yield 0
        yield -1

index = index_generator()
result = []
while l:
    result.append(l.pop(next(index)))
```